# Outlook - Close personal folder fails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm not able to close a personal folder in Outlook 2003.

When I right-click on the folder and chose `Close "Personal folder name"`, I get this error: `The operation failed. The object could not be found.`

When I open the list of Personal folders (either by clicking on `Manage Personal Folders` or on the `Account Settings` page), the incriminated Personal Folder file is not listed.

Nevertheless, the .pst file is present on the local hard disk, and I can access its contents in Outlook.

I want to close the folder, becouse I no longer need it and because it is too large. How can I close that Personal Folder ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by close it?  Do you mean collapse the folder?

Comment: Like I said: Right-click and choose 'Close'. This will close the folder and it is no longer available, until you reconnect it.

Comment: You were not specific about which folder you were selecting. This file on the local drive or on a network drive?

Comment: The file is on the local hard drive. It is a .pst file, that is called "Personal Folder" in Outlook

Comment: .`PST` files can be located on any storage location you want.  Have you tried removing the file from the list of `Data Files` in the `Account Settings` page?  What are the permissions on the folder that contains the `.PST` file?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it doesn't show up in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these strange behaviors point to a corrupted profile.

I tried several things, but did not find a way to recover from this corruption.

Finally I recreated a new profile for the user, and reconfigured it with the Personal Folders required.